# Transliterating chars in Ruby

Tags: ruby, transliteration

I have some conditionals that I'm using to replace one string with another.

For example:

```
    if word == "for"
       word = "4"
```

But what I really want is a condition like:

```
    if word == "for" || word == "FOR" || word == "For" || word == "foR" || word == "FoR" #etc etc
       word = "4"
```

I can't find anything on how to do this. There must be a concise way to write this with Ruby. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Help me to understand:  why would "for" become a transliteration of "four", which is converted to the string "4"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`casecmp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-casecmp) to do a case insensitive compare:

```
if word.casecmp("for") == 0
  word = "4"
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `downcase` method:

```
if word.downcase == 'for'
   word = '4'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I will use [`Regexp#===`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) method.

```
if /\Afor\z/i === word
  word = "4"
end
```

Comment: From the world of golf: `word = "fore!"; /for/i === word #=> true`. From boating: anchors!

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks fixed it. I don't like the other approaches as it was creating some new objects and `== 0` a bit odd... That's why this approach.

Comment: I prefer: `word =~ /\Afor\z/i`, leaving `===` for case statements. For one, who can remember which side of `===` to put the regex?

Comment: quick refer to the documentation, I always do. It is sometimes hard to remember the syntax.. :)

Comment: Since `/\Afor\z/i  =~ word` also works, no need to tax the grey cells. (Of course, one may still forget if it's `=~` or `~=`, but the latter will raise an exception.)